# Graphic Design blogs for our chat ticker

Tags: discussion, chat

Today we implemented the ["Feed" options](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/1240/the-ink-spot?tab=feeds) in our main chat: meta posts now appear as posts in the chat, while mainsite questions appear in a ticker box to the upper left of the chat.

I think it would be helpful and cool to also put graphic design blogs on the ticker, similar to how the [RPG General Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) has an RPG blog feed tied into its ticker.

So, what do you think? Should we do this? And if so--**what graphic design blogs should go on the ticker?**

---

**THESE ARE THE FEEDS THAT HAVE BEEN ADDED SO FAR:**

- [Brand New](http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/)
- [Quipsologies](http://www.underconsideration.com/quipsologies/)
- [Fantastic Maps](http://www.fantasticmaps.com/)
- [Creative Bloq](http://www.creativebloq.com/)
- [This is Colossal](http://www.thisiscolossal.com/)
- [Fast Co Design](http://fastcodesign.com/)
- [Jin Yang's site](http://www.8164.org/) (SE designer)

Feel free to propose some more!

Comment: Excellent idea!

Comment: @yisela I might be being dumb - where are these?

Comment: @user568458 The feed ticker appears in the top left corner of [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) whenever a new item appears on it. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 3):

[Creative Bloq](http://www.creativebloq.com/) is good for news and variety.

Not sure what our ideal amount of posts is - they have several a day.

Answer (score 2):

My first choice would be [Smashing Magazine's Design category](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/category/design/).

They have a decent amount of articles, but not so many that it would flood the ticker.

Answer (score 2):

Under Consideration...either [Brand New](http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/) or [Quipsologies](http://www.underconsideration.com/quipsologies/). Or both.

Answer (score 2):

[Fantastic Maps](http://www.fantasticmaps.com/) has some excellent tutorials and resources for iconography, representation, and so forth. They update very rarely, but are worth keeping an eye on.

Answer (score 2):

I will probably come up with more, but here is

**[Design observer](http://designobserver.com/)**

**[Logo design love](http://www.logodesignlove.com/)**

**[Identity designed](http://identitydesigned.com/)**

Answer (score 2):

You guys might want to consider adding the Stack Exchange Design team blog: [Primer](http://se-primer.tumblr.com).

Primer is about sharing creative links, quotes, articles, and design that's inspiring the Stack Exchange design team. We try to post semi-daily.

--

**EDIT:** I should also note that we tweet out blog posts and other links at our Twitter account, [@StackPrimer](https://twitter.com/StackPrimer), as well.

Comment: Great suggestion! Added

Answer (score 2):

[The Deeply Graphic Designcast](http://thedeependdesign.com/graphic-design-podcast/) (podcast) and [The Deeply Graphic Designcast Blog](http://thedeependdesign.com/blog/)

The podcast is probably the **best** graphic design freelance podcast I've ever listened to.

The blog that Wes McDowell (the owner of the The Deep End Design studio) curates the blog and encourages his listeners of the podcast to submit blog entries.

Answer (score 1):

[**This Is Colossal**](http://www.thisiscolossal.com/) was mentioned by new user [MeachamRob in an answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/19952/3327). I'd not seen it before - it has some really nice interesting stuff.

---

Also [Fast Co Design](http://fastcodesign.com/) have some good stuff sometimes, and some often interesting (but sometimes turgid or needlessly rambling/ranting) opinion pieces. Though much of it is the "overpriced chairs" side of design rather than graphics or art, and some are just blatant plugs for products. I have mixed views about it... but often end up reading it anyway.

Comment: Both excellent! I just added them to the ticker.